# What "type of" declaration represents in Delphi and how can it be used

Tags: delphi

There is some strange code in `Datasnap.DSReflect` unit

```
  TDSAdapterClassType = type of TDSAdapterClass;

  TDSAdapterClass = class(TPersistent)
  private
    FAdapteeInstance: TObject;
  public
    constructor Create(AdapteeInstance: TObject); virtual;
  end;
```

and then it is used like this

```
var
  AdapteeInstance: TObject;
  FClassRef: TPersistentClass;

  Result := TDSAdapterClassType(FClassRef).Create(AdapteeInstance);
```

At first sight it seems just like another way of declaring class reference. But logic implies that it makes no sense to introduce such variation of language construct without adding more functionality to it. Following that logic I discovered that following declarations compile:

```
type
  TypeOfInteger = type of Integer;
  TypeOfByte = type of Byte;

  TRec = record
    x: integer;
  end;
  TypeOfTRec = type of TRec;

  TBytes = array of byte;
  TypeOfTBytes = type of TBytes;
```

Interesting enough, following declaration cannot be compiled.

```
type
  TypeOfString = type of String;
```

So the question is what `type of` actually represents and how can it be used in real life application, besides being some kind of alias for `class of`

**Note:** `type of` does not compile in Delphi 7, it seems that it is introduced later on, it is definitively there in XE, but I don't have Delphi 2007-2010 installed to try it there.

**Update:** I have filled bug report https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-9850

Comment: It behaves like `type` for creating distinct types.

Comment: @TLama: Interesting: I thought (perhaps wrongly) that " TSomethingelse = type TSomething" did that in D7?

Comment: @MartynA, maybe they added that `type of` syntax later, maybe I'm wrong. But from a quick test it seems that e.g. `type TMyInteger = type of Integer;` behaves like `type TMyInteger = type Integer;`. Interesting question which deserves to be answered by someone from EMBT.

Comment: @TLama if you declare variable of type `TypeOfInteger` it shows value nil in debugger, so I would say it is not equivalent to `type`.

Comment: @TLama: Indeed (I wasn't arguing, btw), maybe the addition was related to the introduction of nested definitions.

Comment: @Dalija, I was testing only type-safetiness and in that manner it seems to behave like `type`. But you are right, my assumption is wrong. Even more interesting!

Comment: It's probably just a compiler bug.

Comment: `TFooClass = type of TFoo` is the same as `TFooClass = class of TFoo` but you cannot write `TIntegerClass = class of Integer` because `Integer` is just a type and not a class. `TFoo` is a class type and therefore you can use both. `String` is something between a type and an interface because of the reference counting and maybe they missed to include this or did not know how to tell the compiler :o)

Comment: A compiler bug or a left over of Delphi for .NET, where it would give you a type reference. IOW, `type TInterfaceRef = type of interface`.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Trying to work with the `TIntegerType = type of Integer` produces random results from compiler. Sometimes it compiles sometimes not and the behavior differs from compile to compile. So it is nothing to count on ... maybe also an easter egg :o)

Comment: For me, it always compiles (tried XE7, no update 1 yet).

Comment: It's a means for an intentional internal error, to be able to test how internal errors behave. `type TypeOfInteger = type of Integer;`
`var IT: TypeOfInteger;` `begin IT.Free;` Actually just tested for D2007 and XE2, but won't be surprised if newer versions cannot handle it either.

Comment: @David - I was not being serious.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I did wonder.

Comment: @Sertac, then the IDE must have write many `type of`s somehow covertly in Delphi 2007 thinking of its famous (t)error insight.

Comment: @Dalija The only people that can give an official answer are the developers. You should ask them.

Comment: @David Well I did ask them, didn't I ;-) Some are hanging around here. Joking aside, I do expect some feedback on QP report, but that may take some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not documented. The behaviour is non-repeatable. Some behaviour feels like `class of` but we don't need another way to do that. And `class of` for a value type is nonsensical.

My conclusion is that this must be a compiler bug. The code is invalid and should be rejected by the compiler. The bug is that the code is accepted instead of being rejected.

As can be seen from Hallvard Vassbotn's [article](http://hallvards.blogspot.de/2004/11/object-to-interface-casts.html), `type of` is a feature of the Delphi .net compiler that creates types that map to .net's [`System.RuntimeTypeHandle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtimetypehandle.aspx) type. Loosely speaking therefore, `type of` provides for functionality equivalent to the C# `typeof` operator.

My best guess is that the Delphi desktop compiler accepts `type of` when it should not, as a vestige of the .net compiler.

Comment: It's not a bug, and it's documented. Look at chapter 'Type Compatibility and Identity' in the Delphi Help

Comment: @Sanders no, that's something else altogether

Comment: From everything I could gather so far this is correct answer. `type of` is relic of the past and not usable feature. However, bounty goes to another answer that provided information from where `type of` came from.

Answer (score 6):

In Delphi.Net we have the following definitions in SysUtils:

```
type
  TInterfaceRef = type of interface;

  function Supports(const Instance: TObject; const IID: TInterfaceRef): Boolean; overload; inline;
```

So it was some kind of replacement for `class of` that can be used for interface types.

The following document mentions a "Type reference syntax (type of Interface)":
http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/29780

Here's some more info:
http://hallvards.blogspot.de/2004/11/object-to-interface-casts.html

Comment: So this is .NET relic. Has anyone be able to make something useful out of it in current compilers, because I could not. So far it still falls into bug category.

Answer (score 5):

It seems to be related to PTypeInfo based in the TypeKind as you can write this:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

type
  TIntType = type of Integer;
  TInt64Type = type of Int64;

var
  intType: TIntType;
  int64Type: TInt64Type;
begin
  try
    intType := Integer;
    Assert(Pointer(intType) = TypeInfo(Integer));
    intType := Cardinal;
    Assert(Pointer(intType) = TypeInfo(Cardinal));
    intType := NativeInt;
    Assert(Pointer(intType) = TypeInfo(NativeInt));
    int64Type := Int64;
    Assert(Pointer(int64Type) = TypeInfo(Int64));
    int64Type := UInt64;
    Assert(Pointer(int64Type) = TypeInfo(UInt64));
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

But it does not work properly with all types and throws internal compiler errors for some.

Comment: I still think it is a remainder from .NET times, where it made sense. It was probably never properly implemented in the Windows and derived compilers.

Comment: @Rudy Hard to see how it made sense there

Comment: It really returned reflection data, IIRC. But that's quite a few years ago, so I may be wrong.

Comment: @Rudy Perhaps it's the equivalent of the .net `typeof` operator