# Why does the declaration of a TDictionary with a type as key throw an internal L2095 error?

Tags: delphi, generics, delphi-xe2

Would anyone know why the following code throws an internal L2095 error?

Apparently the compiler has a problem with the dictionary's key being a class type.

Anyone know of a work-around?

(PS: the error isn't thrown when I don't include the `TestDict := TDictTest.Create;` portion or when the key is something else than a class type)

```
  TTestClass = class
  end;

  TTypeOfTestClass = type of TTestClass;

  TDictTest = TDictionary<TTypeOfTestClass,Integer>;

var
  TestDict: TDictTest;

implementation

initialization

  TestDict := TDictTest.Create;
  TestDict.Free
```

**Added after answer**:

Apparently this is about me having instinctively used "`type of`" instead of "`class of`". "`Type of`" is accepted by the compiler, hence the confusion.
A reference to a question related to this: [What "type of" declaration represents in Delphi and how can it be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27555272/what-type-of-declaration-represents-in-delphi-and-how-can-it-be-used)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think "type of ..." is even allowed. Use

```
TTypeOfTestClass = class of TTestClass;
```

instead.

Comment: I should indeed have used "class of"! I do in other parts of my code, but for some reason I used "type of" this time and it does compile, strangely enough. It appears to be accepted everywhere except in the TDictionary declaration. Odd. But thanks!